# ReferenceError: Faye is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, thin, faye

I am trying to do a chatbox with ruby on rails, using faye. It runs well with WEBrick server, my boss asks me to implement it with apache server, i tried it, but have some errors(showed by firebug):

```
    TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
           var client = new Faye.Client('http://192.168.2.1:9292/faye');
    ReferenceError: Faye is not defined
           var client = new Faye.Client('http://192.168.2.1:9292/faye');
```

gem 'faye'  is included in the Gemfile, faye version is '0.8.8'; 'thin' is installed. thin version: '1.5.0'
Anyone can help to solve these problems? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in the html file

`<script src="http://localhost:9000/realtime_videos/client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`